# single room for single user in socket.io

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I am working on nodejs and angularjs. I am using socket.io to show progress for the ongoing process.

On client side

```
let socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('room',{roomId:user_id});

socket.on('data',function(data){
 console.log("data -=- ",data);
})
```

on server side

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(de) {
    console.log("disconnected",de)
  });
  socket.on('room',function(d){
    socket.join(d.roomId);
  })
})

app.use(function(req,res,next){
 req.io = io; next();
});
```

I am sending the roomId with my post request in body; When the api is called I collect the roomId from req.body and then emit the event.

```
req.io.sockets.in(roomId).emit('data',{roomId:roomId,msg:'message'});
```

When I run this on localhost for single user it worked properly. But when I call the api which emits the event for two separate user with separate roomId. The user which requests first gets nothing.

If user1 with roomId = 1 connects just before user2 with roomId = 2 then user1 does not receive the 'data' event. Only user2 is receiving it.

I could not find any solution for this. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By looking this what i come to know that you are doing every thing right the problem that is happening what i think is in `req.body` I think you are just storing the roomID of the last user so when you call the emit method it always fires the event only to one room

```
req.io.sockets.in(roomId).emit('data',{roomId:roomId,msg:'message'});
```

In order to send the events to 2 different users your roomId should be changed for each user for the testing purpose use 2 different browsers for testing might be it work

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Now just  log the value of roomID in the function where you write emit function and look is that value is changing or not